# Only adjust child fragment when soft keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

My app is based on the single activity architecture, and I have a parent fragment inside the activity which has a navigation bar at the bottom and a frame layout on which I place other child fragments.

One of the child fragments has an `EditText` at the bottom, but when the soft-keyboard is up, I want that the view is only adjusted of the child fragment.

I have already tried adjust pan or resize options but nothing is working for this specific use case.

When I use the following code, it adjusts the `EditText` but the bottom bar of the parent fragment also goes up when keyboard is shown, which is not what I am trying to do.

`requireActivity().window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN or WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN)`

Any help will be appreciated.